# How to map Java HashMap<String, Pojo> variableName to typescript

Tags: java, typescript, spring-boot, hashmap, angular7

I am trying to figure out how to create Typescript interface for `HashMap<String, Pojo>` I have tried the below variations but:

```
export interface ServerResponse {
    // forWhomAdd: Array<ForWhomAdd>;  // size/length is undefined
    // forWhomAdd: Map<string, Address>; // size/length is undefined
    forWhomAdd: { [firstLastName: string]: Address }; // How do I access keys and values?
}
```

I'd prefer not to do this the third way because I'm loosing my types which I'm trying to define.

This is how it looks when I log it:

```
{testKey: {property: value, prop: value}}
```

So I can get the Object by:

```
let serRes: ServerResponse = data;
serRes.testKey // gives back the object
```

But I don't know keys and I need to loop over serRes.

Comment: Have you tried using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of all the keys in the object?

Comment: I tried this but it gives me undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data has list of  `ServerResponse`.

```
let serRes: Array<ServerResponse> = data;
```

> But I don't know keys and I need to loop over serRes.

you can get the values of the Object with keys() method of `Object`class.

```
Object.keys(this.serRes).map(key => this.serRes[key])
```

**UPDATE :**

I have created stackblitz for your case check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmfcyz?file=src/app/app.component.ts).